# Clean Guava way to handle possibly-null collection

Tags: java, guava

I have a method which takes an argument `Collection<Foo> foos`, which could be NULL.  I want to end up with a local copy of the input as an `ImmutableSet`.  Right now my code looks like this:

```
if (foos == null)
{
  this.foos = ImmutableSet.of();
}
else
{
  this.foos = ImmutableSet.copyOf(foos);
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?  If `foos` was a simple parameter I could do something like `Objects.firstNonNull(foos, Optional.of())` but I'm not sure if there is something similar to handle collections.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't see why you couldn't use `Objects.firstNonNull`:

```
this.foos = ImmutableSet.copyOf(Objects.firstNonNull(foos, ImmutableSet.of()));
```

You can save some typing with static imports, if that's your thing:

```
import static com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf;
import static com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.of;
// snip...
this.foos = copyOf(Objects.firstNonNull(foos, of()));
```

Comment: +1 And it might be worth pointing out that `copyOf` is smart enough to simply return the input if it's an `ImmutableSet`.

Comment: @PaulBellora I do believe that you just did. `:)`

Comment: Also `ImmutableSet.<Foo>of()` might be necessary unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

A `Collection` is a reference like any other, so you could do:

```
ImmutableSet.copyOf(Optional.fromNullable(foos).or(ImmutableSet.of()));
```

But that is becoming quite a handful to write. More simple:

```
foos == null ? ImmutableSet.of() : ImmutableSet.copyOf(foos);
```

Comment: The second example has the advantage of not creating an empty collection when one is not needed. The answer by MattBall would always create the empty `Set` even if the passed collection is not null.

Comment: @JohnB `ImmutableSet.of()` [returns a singleton](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html#line.83).