# Is there an elegant way for handling null Collections in ImmutableList.copyOf?

Tags: guava

I'm trying to make a copy of a collection that can be null which results in `ImmutableList.copyOf(collection)` failing.

I don't want to do a null check before making the copy like

```
CollectionUtils.isEmpty(collection) 
   ? ImmutableList.of() 
   : ImmutableList.copyOf(collection)
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this for lists and any collection in general?

Comment: That's about as elegant as it gets. You can put it in a utility method if you want to keep your code DRY. But no matter how you do it, as long as you allow nulls, you _will_ have to null check, no way around that.

Comment: `ImmutableList.copyOf(firstNonNull(collection, ImmutableList.of())`, with static import from `MoreObjects`.

Comment: Very nice Ben Manes. Please add this as an answer

Comment: (see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/17454217/869736)